# Error while downloading HTTPS files using wget

Tags: downloads, wget, https, restricted

If I try to download the some http files, Then `wget` works just fine (eg: `wget download_link`). But when i try to download https files using `wget` then I'm getting the following error

```
http request sent 
403 forbidden
```

My problem is, I can't download http files in my college wifi. So when I try to download the file, `wget` will send the http request to the server. Eventually, the download will be blocked.

To download the https file, I've tried using the following command

```
wget https://download_link
```

How to download https files (username and password is there in the download link too)?

Are there any extra options needed with `wget`?

Comment: BTW, just for confirmation, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Enthusiast when posting a question, please post more information. The `wget` command you say were failing - here it would have been great to have had the exact output from the command, for debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially `wget` does not support the https downloads in some destributions. We need to compile the source code manually using openssl. After that we can do https downloads

Link to compile the wget using openssl :

[How to compile the wget source code](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=119)

Comment: Has someone tried this and can verify that it works?

Answer (score 8):

In order to use the `https` protocol you will have to add the `--secure-protocol=protocol` option. The protocol argument can be one of:

- auto
- SSLv2
- SSLv3
- TLSv1

There are also further related options like `--no-check-certificate` telling `wget` to not check server's certificate and many more.

This will prompt for password

```
wget --user=username --ask-password --no-check-certificate https://foo.bar.com
```

In this you will have to provide the password

```
wget --user=username --password --no-check-certificate https://foo.bar.com
```

[Source: GNU Wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options)

Comment: I have already tried all the options, But its still unable to download. Major problem is wget sending its first request in http format, Because of that i'm getting the error message

Comment: @Roshanshetty is impossible that wget sends the first part as http, since wget do first a ssl handshake directly with the server, then it start to transmit headers and such. I recommend you to **edit your question** and provide the results of each try.

Comment: @Braiam Finally i got the anwer, initially wget doesn't support https downloads in some destribution, We have to compile the source code and then we can do the https downloads

Answer (score 2):

eg. `wget --user=user --password=password --no-check-certificate https://host.domain.tld/directory/file.ext`

if the certificate check works you might as well just

```
wget https://user:password@host.domain.tld/directory/file.ext
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay
I have already tried all the options, But its still unable to download. Major problem is wget sending its first request in http format, Because of that i'm getting the error message

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get -y install curl && curl https://user:password@host.domain.tld/directory/file.ext -O`

Comment: @Roshanshetty why you marked this as your accepted answer if you still have problems?

Comment: @Braiam
Because, HTTPS download doesn't wotk without compiling the source code. But once we compiled the source code, We need the some options(described in the above answer) to download the https files

Comment: @Braiam both are answers(my answer as well as Feczo's answer, But i cant make my answer as "solution" till 2 days